# SQL Server restore database files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Say I'm using SQL Server and have set sa password in security. Can the database files be copied to another computer (running same SQL Server setup but with different sa password security) and restored as database of same name and get access to all the data?

Answer (score 2):

> would like to secure or prevent it from being accessed or copied (tables, views, data etc)

No, this is impossible and anybody telling you otherwise is selling you snake oil. What you want is called DRM and SQL Server cannot do DRM. At best you can prevent *accidental* media loss (ie. your IP ends up on a stolen laptop or on disk in a flea market and somebody simply reads the precious table and views definition) and that scenario is prevented with on-disk encryption (either TDE or BitLocker will do). But you cannot prevent an administrator from inspecting your database.